# jsPDF | dataKey of autoTable not work in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

My PDF does not change when I use columnStyles with dataKey property,
but my code works properly when I use the number instead of dataKey .

This is code that works incorrectly:

```
head = [{title: 'توضیحات', dataKey: 'MoreDescribe'},
{title: 'امکانات', dataKey: 'properties'},
{title: 'مبلغ خرید', dataKey: 'id'}]

body = [
[{content: ' قابل استفاده'},
{content: 'اندازه مناسب'},
{content: '10000 تومان'}],

[{content: ' قابل استفاده'},
{content: 'اندازه مناسب'},
{content: '10000 تومان'}],

[{content: ' قابل استفاده'},
{content: 'اندازه مناسب'},
{content: '10000 تومان'}]
]

printAll(){
const doc = new jsPDF();
autoTable(doc, {
      head: [this.head],
    body: this.body,
      headStyles: { font: 'Shabnam',halign: 'center',valign: "middle"}, // work
      bodyStyles: { font: 'Shabnam', halign: 'center', valign: "middle" }, // work

      columnStyles: {  id: { cellWidth: 5000 },properties:{cellWidth:700},MoreDescribe:{cellWidth:500} } // not work
    })
}
```

my result is:
[image]

if I change the

```
columnStyles: { id: { cellWidth: 5000 },properties:{cellWidth:700},MoreDescribe:{cellWidth:500} }
```

to

```
columnStyles: { 1: { cellWidth: 5000 },2:{cellWidth:700},3:{cellWidth:500} }
```

cellWidth style applies to my table.
but I want to use dataKey. how can I do it?